How to call a macro when the value of a cell (boolean variable) is changed by another cell in the context of automatic calculation enabled?
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(byval Target As Range) works when the value of the cell is changed ("True" to "False" or "False" to "True") using the keyboard.
Is there any way to call a macro when changing a cell's value is a consequence of changes in other cells?
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Dim KeyCells1 As Range
    Dim KeyCells2 As Range
    Set KeyCells1 = Range("D8") 'Seleção de ativo
    Set KeyCells2 = Range("F42") ' Estado do alarme
    
    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells1, Range(Target.Address)) _
      Is Nothing Then
        Macro1
    End If
    
    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells2, Range(Target.Address)) _
      Is Nothing Then
        Macro2
    End If
End Sub


Please share the formulas in D8 and F42.

You need to trigger on worksheet_calculate:
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    ' Static variable to keep track of the previous value
    Static prevValue As Variant
    
    ' Get the current value of the target cell
    Dim currentValue As Variant
    currentValue = Me.Range("A2").Value
    
    ' Check if the value has changed
    If currentValue <> prevValue Then
        ' Your code goes here
        MsgBox "The value of cell A1 has changed to: " & currentValue
        
        ' Update the previous value
        prevValue = currentValue
    End If
End Sub


For the case of 2 cells you can use macro like this:
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Dim KeyCells1 As Range
    Dim KeyCells2 As Range
    Set KeyCells1 = Range("D8") 'Seleçao de ativo
    Set KeyCells2 = Range("F42") ' Estado do alarme

    ' Static variables to keep track of the previous values
    Static prev1 As Boolean, prev2 As Boolean
    
    ' Check if the value has changed
    If KeyCells1.Value <> prev1 Then
        ' Perform your macro
        Macro1
        ' Update the previous value
        prev1 = KeyCells1.Value
    End If
    If KeyCells2.Value <> prev2 Then
        ' Perform your macro
        Macro2
        ' Update the previous value
        prev2 = KeyCells2.Value
    End If
    
End Sub

